# Custom Fields drop-down options based on selection in another drop-down?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

When I create a Custom Field drop-down, it possible to have a second custom drop-down that the selctions are populated based on the selection of the first drop-down?

EXAMPLE:

If Drop-down A has no selection picked yet, then Drop-down B is empty (has no options to pick at all).

If Drop-down A has a selection of ITEM 1, then Drop-down B selections are populated as Yellow, Red, or Green.

If Drop-down A has a selection of ITEM 2, then Drop-down B selections are populated as Sky, Ground, or Water.

Comment: In what context? Profile form? FormBuilder form? Event registration form? Contact edit form?

Comment: @Coleman Contact edit form

Comment: With all the recent work I've done on SearchKit-based Autocomplete widgets, your request is very nearly possible, we'd just need a couple more tweaks to the form code to get it to include the other field values as part of the query. If you're interested in sponsoring a few hours work by the Core Team to get that done, please reach out to me on chat.civicrm.org (my name is the same there).

Comment: @coleman reaching out!!